# Export gridview to excel, and replace one column

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, datatable, export

I need to export gridview data to excel on button click.

But in gridview one column data need to be changed with data that is another table from database.

For example:
Gridview showing employee ID(empid)  from one table but I need to show username in place of empid in excel data.

The export to Excel:

```
protected void btmexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=Export.xls";
    Response.ClearContent(); 
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);                                   
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"; 
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); 
    HtmlForm frm = new  HtmlForm(); 
    grd_data.Parent.Controls.Add(frm); 
    frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";         
    frm.Controls.Add(grd_data);frm.RenderControl(htw);     
    Response.Write(sw.ToString()); 
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Better show us some code, so we can help you more efficient!

Comment: This Is code that I am using to export excel                    protected void btmexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { string attachment = "attachment; filename=Export.xls";
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
 Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
 HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
 grd_data.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
 frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server"; frm.Controls.Add(grd_data);frm.RenderControl(htw);Response.Write(sw.ToString());   Response.End();}

Comment: Please read this .. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and accept the edit on your post!

Comment: I have two table one is binding user contact details (tblusercontact) that has field empid , contact number , address that is simplt showing on page when i click on button it is easily exporting data to excel but I need to change column empid from table tblusercontact need to be change from table tbluserdetails that has field empid username , I need to show corresponding username of that particular id . I need just some logic ,what approach should i implement.